# MySQL SELECT all except where two columns have specific data together

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry the title is so confusing, below is my table (example) and what I am trying to achieve.

```
uid | title     | comment      | duration    | timestamp
---------------------------------------------------------
1   | test      | test         | d           | 2013-09-15 12:00:00
2   | test      | test         | w           | 2013-09-15 12:00:00
3   | test      | test         | m           | 2013-09-30 12:00:00
4   | test      | test         | y           | 2013-12-31 12:00:00
5   | test      | test         | d           | 2013-09-16 12:00:00
```

Basically I need a query that SELECT * from this table except when `duration = d` AND timestamp = `2013-09-15 12:00:00` together. So the only record that should be excluded from the results is row 1.

What I need seems so simple and I am sure I am missing something, but I am having a real hard time with it...

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Choose any answer and don't forget `;`

Comment: Both answers had no semicolon at the end, which is required in MySQL

Comment: @zaquest: nitpicker :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from table 
where not (duration = 'd' AND timestamp = '2013-09-15 12:00:00');
```

Comment: Or, if you want to use de Morgan: `where duration <> 'd' OR timestamp <> '2013-09-15 12:00:00'`. Depending on your index, one might perform faster than the other. (as soon as duration <> d, it can return the row without checking timestamp)

Comment: I prefer the "NOT(...AND...)" over "NOT ... OR NOT ..." because it's easier to understand (at least for me). And the optimizer of my Teradata is rewriting it anyway :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE duration != 'd' OR timestamp != '2013-09-15 12:00:00';
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1784/1).

Comment: This doesn't work as excluded all data with that date and all data with that duration. For example, running that query does not return row 5, but it needs to.

Comment: This is correct.  Using AND requires both conditions to be true.

Comment: Running this query excludes row 5 from the results. I have just run it and it does not return row 5.

Comment: `not (duration = 'd' AND timestamp = '2013-09-15 12:00:00')` is not the same as `duration != 'd' AND timestamp != '2013-09-15 12:00:00'`

Comment: Laws of de Morgan: !(a AND b) = (!a OR !b). This answer is wrong: if duration equals 'd, your AND will already fail, but it should only fail if the timestamp is wrong too.

Comment: I am adding another AND statement in the query - `AND comment = 'test'` to to reduce the results further... Does that make a difference as to which query works. Because yours definitely excludes row 5 and the `not` version doesn't...

Comment: It's excluding all rows where any of both conditions is true, i.e.  1,2,5 removed